# Is there a service that allows real-time (google docs-style) collaboration while filling forms?

Tags: collaboration, educational, survey

I am looking to create a simple form with ~5 pages, each of which shows students an instructional video with a question at the end and presents them a text box to answer that question. I would like to force a response in the text box before moving on. I know this is easy with platforms such as Qualtrics XM, Google Forms, Microsoft Forms, Survey Monkey, etc.

*Here's the hard part*: I also need students to be able to work collaboratively while filling the forms. In other words, I want them to be able to see what their 2-3 group mates are writing in real-time (similar to how collaboration works in Google Docs and Overleaf).

I have tried Qualtrics XM, Google Forms, Microsoft Forms, and Survey Monkey, but none of them meet my collaboration requirement. I have also tried google docs, but none of them meet my "force responses" requirement. (students can just move on to the next page/slide/etc. without answering the question.

Does any such software exist that fulfills both the collaboration and "force responses" requirments?